# How can I find and replace with a new line?

Tags: vim, text-processing, sed, csv

I have a CSV delimited by commas and I want to delimit it by newlines instead.

Input:

```
a, b, c
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

I've written Java parsers that do this stuff, but couldn't this be done with `vim` or some other tool?

`sed` isn't working for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start
cat > infile.csv << __EOF__
a, b, c
__EOF__
cat infile.csv
sed 's/, /\n/g' infile.csv > outfile.csv

cat outfile.csv
```

Comment: This script works as expected on my Ubuntu system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to [Iain's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/591/iain), you can also use `tr`:

```
$ echo a,b,c | tr ',' '\n'
a
b
c
```

Both answers assume that the CSV is simple (that is, all commas are field separators). If you have something like `a,"b,c",d` where `b,c` is a single field, then things get more difficult

Comment: @Mrozek: how do I use tr with the input and output file?

Comment: @simpatico `cat input | tr ',' '\n' > output`

Comment: `tr ',' '\n' < input > output` avoids the UUOC.

Comment: @kojiro Yes, but I do not and never will care about that :). I even do `cat foo | grep bar`; I suspect the UUOC fanatics burn me in effigy every night

Comment: # As a relative newcomer to Linux/bash, I've been a bit puzzled by the UUOC issue; So, for general info; To cat or not to cat, that is the question...  I just time tested 1000 (random) ASCII text files (total 307666 lines)...  `cat file* | grep sometext` vs `<file* grep sometext` ... 'cat' is slower for real, user, and sys times: real(0m2.396s/0m2.121s): user(0m6.012s/0m3.172s); sys(0m2.264s/0m1.000s) ... (does time matter?.. sometimes yes, soemtimes no)... but the times are certainly different

Comment: @fred Nobody's arguing that avoiding the extra command isn't beneficial, it's whether or not you actually care. If I'm writing a script that's going to be used by lots of other people, I'll make an effort to do it right. If I'm running a command that's going to cat a 50 line file one time and pass it to another process, I really don't care how many `cat`s are involved. The 2 seconds I could've saved by skipping the cat are voided by the 10 seconds it takes me to check that command's man page to remember if it takes a filename argument and what switch it is

Answer (score 21):

Seems like the other answers achieve what you want, and a scriptable tool seems the most appropriate choice.

But you asked about vim, so here's how you do it there:

```
%s/, /\r/g
```

That is, replace every comma+space with a carriage return. This will then be interpreted as the appropriate line ending character for the file. (You can check this by searching for `\r` -- it won't be found).

Answer (score 2):

If your file is delimited by ', ' (commas followed by space) then

`sed 's/, /\n/g' filename.csv >newfile`

will do the job. If its delimited by ',' (commas without spaces) then

`sed 's/,/\n/g' filename.csv >newfile`

will work.

or change the `\n` to `\o12` if your flavour of sed doesn't like it.

Comment: this replaced it with space and not new lines. Output: a b c

Comment: @simpatico: Ok - I 'see' the problem now, your example output wasn't formatted correctly.

Comment: @lain: this doens't work with \n . Did you try it? the \ disappears while the n is appended. a, b --> an b

Comment: @simpatico: I did test it and it works ok.

Comment: @Iain GNU `sed` and `sed` (some of which are strictly POSIX-compliant) need not necessarily be the same...And I am pretty sure the functionality you tested is guaranteed on GNU `sed` *only*. With the others, it may - or may not - work. Like playing poker. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The use of `\n` in a `s` replacement text in sed is allowed, but not mandated, by POSIX. GNU sed does it, but there are implementations that output `\n` literally.

You can use any POSIX-compliant awk. Set the input field separator `FS` to a regular expression and the output field separator `ORS` to a string (with the usual backslash escapes). The assignment `$1=$` is needed to rebuild the line to use the different field separator.

```
awk -vFS=', *' -vOFS='\n' '{$1=$1; print}'
```

(This assumes that your input contains plain comma-and-whitespace-separated values, without any quoting. If there is quoting, you need to move to a real CSV parser in a language such as Perl or Python.)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
perl6 -pe 's:g/ "," \s /\n/;' 

#OR

perl6 -ne '.split(", ").join("\n").put;'
```

Also, if you're concerned about embedded newlines, commas-within-quotes, etc., use Raku's `Text::CSV` module:

```
raku -MText::CSV -e '.join("\n").put for csv(in => lines, sep => ", ");'
```

Sample Input:

```
a, b, c
```

Sample Output (all code above):

```
a
b
c
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701805/227738
https://raku.org