# Is there a command line utility to transpose a csv-file?

Tags: text-processing, csv

Given a file like so

```
First,Last,Age
Cory,Klein,27
John Jacob,Smith,30
```

Is there a command line utility to transpose the contents so the output appears like so

```
First,Cory,John Jacob
Last,Klein,Smith
Age,27,30
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'puts CSV.parse(STDIN).transpose.map &:to_csv' < in.csv > out.csv
```

Comment: Given the age of this question I will justify my changing to this as the accepted: a) This answer is much more succinct than Gilles' `python`, b) `ruby` is no less portable than `python`, and c) this also shows how to pass the input/output files. Bravo @luikore, and welcome to Unix & Linux. Please do stick around.

Comment: one caveat, in the csv, fields must be quoted

Comment: @yosefrow No need quoting. I tested the command before I posted this answer.

Comment: ok should have said "may" then. It didnt work for me until I quoted all fields. Might have to do with my data content

Answer (score 35):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/2776078 :

```
$ apt-get install csvtool
```

And then convert

```
$ csvtool transpose input.csv > ouput.csv
```

Or in pipeline

```
$ ... | csvtool transpose - | ...
```

Comment: beautiful. Only `... | csvtranspose | ...` would beat that, syntax-wise.

Comment: you can set alias for it

Comment: and I found that pip install doesn't work for csvtool

Answer (score 21):

CSV parsing is not easily done with POSIX tools only, unless you are using a simplified CSV variant with no quoting (so that commas can't appear in a field). Even then, this task doesn't seem easy to do with `awk` or other text processing to tool. You can use Perl with [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV), Python with [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), R with [`read.csv`](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html), Ruby with [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), … (All of these are part of the standard library of the respective language except for Perl.)

For example, in Python:

```py
import csv, sys
rows = list(csv.reader(sys.stdin))
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for col in xrange(0, len(rows[0])):
    writer.writerow([row[col] for row in rows])
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick & dirty [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution :

```
c=1
file=file.txt
num_lines=$(wc -l < "$file")

for ((i=0; i<num_lines; i++)) {
    cut -d, -f$c "$file" | paste -sd ','
    ((c++))
}
```

Comment: what does /tmp/l represent? Additionally, would it not be simpler to loop through the columns rather than lines, something along the lines of `for ((i=1; i<=$num_cols; ++i)); do paste -s -d, <(cut -f$i -d, file.txt); done`

Comment: Note that this works for OP's input, but only because their data has the same number of rows and columns, which usually is not the case.

Comment: csv has specification regarding dpuble quotes , i.e. `this "is" example` cell is encoded `"this ""is"" example"` I am not convinced if this solution handles such cases properly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the CSV file is a *simple* CSV file, meaning no field contains embedded delimiters or newlines, you may use [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash transpose --field-separator=',' < input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the suggested limitation (no quoting, no embedded commas), it is simple in awk (as it would be in perl not taking into account over a thousand lines in `CSV.pm`, 2300 lines in `csv.rb` — python has only 450 lines in `csv.py`).

Here is an example for awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { width=0; }
{
    max = split($0, list, ",");
    # printf "%d:%s\n", NR, $0;
    if (width < max)
        width = max;
    for (n = 1; n <= max; ++n) {
        sub("^[     ]*","",list[n]);
        sub("[  ]*$","",list[n]);
        # printf "\t%d:%s\n", n, list[n];
        if ( columns[n] != "" ) {
            columns[n] = columns[n] ", ";
        }
        columns[n] = columns[n] list[n];
    }
}
END {
    # printf "%d columns\n", width;
    for (n = 1; n <= width; ++n) {
        printf "%s\n", columns[n];
    }
}
```

By the way: the given example had extra space which OP assumed would be removed; the other examples did not address this detail.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known a Perl_6)

```perl
raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN); @a = [Z] @a; csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT);'
```

Adding this to the excellent list of suggestions already posted. It should be obvious to Perl-aficionados that the Raku ecosystem is somewhat similar in the way Modules get loaded at the command line (e.g. `-MText::CSV`).

Note, the first and third statements above are a bare-bones way to validate/output CSV files using Raku. So CSV output will contain double-quoted strings where necessary.

This question asks for transposition, and thus the extra (second) statement transposes rows/columns (representation within the `@a` array).

Sample Input:

```
First,Last,Age
Cory,Klein,27
John Jacob,Smith,30
```

Sample Output:

```
First,Cory,"John Jacob"
Last,Klein,Smith
Age,27,30
```

---

**ADDENDUM:**  Code below for those who absolutely insist their CSV files don't need validation by a CSV-parser (same output as above, *sans* double-quotes):

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines.map(*.split(",")); .join(",").put for [Z] @a;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e '.join(",").put for [Z] lines.map: *.split(",");'
```

---

[https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-[]_(reduction_metaoperators)](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-%5B%5D_(reduction_metaoperators))
https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.pdf
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose with an awk one-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]= (i in a?a[i] OFS :"")$i}END{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print a[i] }' input_file
First,Cory,John Jacob
Last,Klein,Smith
Age,27,30
```