# How to split a single line of fields delimited by commas into multiple lines with a specific number of fields in each line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like so

```
Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based,Random
```

For `n=2`, output must be like so

```
Hello,Hi
Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random
```

For `n=3`, output must be like so

```
Hello,Hi,Hullo
Hammers,Based,Random
```

How could I accomplish this using awk/sed?

Edit: `n` is a factor of number of fields

Comment: For n=4, should the last line be `Based,Random` or `Based,Random,,`? The former does not fulfill "specific number of fields", but the latter does not entirely come from "splitting a single line of fields".

Comment: Ed Morton is correct, I forgot to mention that it can be assumed that number of fields divides evenly by 'n'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -v n=2 -F',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%n ? FS : ORS)}' file
Hello,Hi
Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random

$ awk -v n=3 -F',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%n ? FS : ORS)}' file
Hello,Hi,Hullo
Hammers,Based,Random
```

In your question you didn't address how to handle cases where the number of fields don't divide evenly by `n` so I haven't addressed it here either.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with `tr` and `paste`:

For n=2,

```
$ <input tr ',' '\n' | paste  -d ',' - -
Hello,Hi
Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random
```

For n=3,

```
$ <input tr ',' '\n' | paste  -d ',' - - -
Hello,Hi,Hullo
Hammers,Based,Random
```

Answer (score 2):

Using perl:

```
$ echo 'Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based,Random' | 
    perl -F, -le '
      BEGIN { $n = shift };
      for ($i=0; $i < @F; $i += $n) {
         print join(",", @F[$i .. ($i + $n - 1)]);
      }' 2
Hello,Hi
Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random
```

This uses the first argument as the number of entries printed per output line (using variable `$n`).  STDIN and any filename arguments are used as the input.

Due to the `-F,` option (which implicitly enables the `-a` and `-n` options), it automatically reads each input line and splits it on commas into array `@F`, then iterates over the indices of the array, `$n` items at a time.  `$n` elements are printed on each output line.

NOTE: use the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module if you need to parse actual CSV with quoted fields and commas embedded in quotes rather than simple comma-delimited input.

Output with an argument of `3` instead of `2`:

```
$ echo 'Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based,Random' | perl -F, -le 'BEGIN{$n = shift};for($i=0;$i<@F;$i+=$n){print join(",",@F[$i..($i+$n-1)])}' 3
Hello,Hi,Hullo
Hammers,Based,Random
```

And again with `4`:

```
$ echo 'Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based,Random' | perl -F, -le 'BEGIN{$n = shift};for($i=0;$i<@F;$i+=$n){print join(",",@F[$i..($i+$n-1)])}' 4
Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random,,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/,/\n/2;P;D'
```

```bash
m=3
sed "s/,/\\n/$m;P;D"
```

Comment: I can't explain to myself how someone could have downvotes this answer. It's really elegant.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini Assumes a particular non-standard implementation of `sed`, and contains a code injection vulnerability unless one assumes full control over the value in `$m`.

Comment: @Kusalananda What isn't standard in this `sed`?

Comment: @DanieleGrassini Inserting a newline using `\n` in the replacement string of the `s` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda how we can speak about security implications with out knowing the full environnement? any of the other code coud be considered potentially dangerous in some circumstances. To mee, in regards to this question which dosnt state anything else that "How to split.." seem to be a good solutions.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think is well supported anyway. Work with `GNU sed` with `--posix` flags and with `busybox sed`. And if some implementations of `sed` does not support it, is just matters to add it in line a part i think.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini Your original enquiry was about how someone could have downvoted this answer, not whether the code could run on some number of various systems.  I know how to modify it to work (and be safe), so there's no need to convince me of anything.  Note too that using `--posix` does not _remove_ all non-POSIX features from GNU `sed` (EDIT: It does not remove behaviour that is explicitly left unspecified in the POSIX spec.)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` again,
input any suite of values separated by `,` and newlines,
output a fixed-width csv:

```
awk '{printf((FNR>1?(FNR-1)%n?",":ORS:"")$0)}END{print ""}' RS='[,\n]' n=4 <<END
Hello
Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based
Random
END

Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` :

```bash
echo 'Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based,Random' | perl -ne '
    @L = (/,?([^,]*,[^,]*)/g);
    $"="\n" ; print "@L"
'
```

---

This question make me think to `python` [zip/iter builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```bash
python3 -c 'from sys import argv as F; J = "\n".join
_, sep, data, sz = F
L = [*map(sep.join, zip(*[iter(data.split(sep))]*int(sz)))]
print(J(L))
' , "Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based,Random" 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put for .split(",").rotor(3);'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers,Based,Random
```

Sample Output with `.rotor(3)` (from above):

```
Hello Hi Hullo
Hammers Based Random
```

Sample Output changing above to `.rotor(2)`:

```
Hello Hi
Hullo Hammers
Based Random
```

The code above is a bare-bones implementation in Raku (returning single whitespace between columns). The `rotor()` call determines the number of columns [ see discussion below regarding the difference between `rotor()` and `batch()` ]. Just add a call to `.join()` if you want to join columns using commas, tabs, pipes, etc.:

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.join(",").put for .split(",").rotor(2);'  file
Hello,Hi
Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random
```

Note, by default `rotor()` only returns full groups and will drop partial groups at the very end. So perfoming a `rotor(4)` call on the above six-element sample will result in a single line of output, 4 elements long. To ensure no loss of data, use `rotor(4, :partial)` or `batch(4)`.

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.join(",").put for .split(",").rotor(4);'  file
Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers

#COMPARE TO:

~$ raku -ne '.join(",").put for .split(",").batch(4);'  file
Hello,Hi,Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random
```

---

Processing by an authentic CSV-parser (e.g. Raku's `Text::CSV` module) will validate the resulting CSV file. See the URL below for examples.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701805/227738
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([^,]*,[^,]*),/\1\
/g' input_file
Hello,Hi
Hullo,Hammers
Based,Random
```

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/\1\
/g' input_file
Hello,Hi,Hullo
Hammers,Based,Random
```

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the obvious awk/Perl/sed approach I can recommend [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

It can extract and modify Text based data very well and is more intuitive to use that it‘s counterparts.

Comment: `...is more intuitive to use...` Please add, at least, an example to show how.