# Replace space between filepaths with newline

Tags: text-processing, string

How can I replace spaces with new lines on an input like:

`/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5` etc...

To obtain the following:

```
/path/to/file
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file3
/path/to/file4
/path/to/file5
```

#### Note

I'm posting this question to help other users, it was not easy to find a useful answer on UNIX SE until I started to type this question. After that I found the following:

#### Related question

[How can I find and replace with a new line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/how-can-i-find-and-replace-with-a-new-line)

Comment: [question with +922 total votes: How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/918886/52074)

Comment: ls /path/to/ | xargs echo | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g'

Comment: What produces that text, and what do you want to use it for? If it's a list of actual pathnames, just replacing spaces by newlines may obviously mangle pathnames that contain embedded spaces, such as `/User/myself/VirtualBox VMs/`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Gilles has written an excelent answer here (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105655/49721) explaining why _"A space-separated list of file names doesn't really work: what if one of the file names contained spaces?"_

Answer (score 236, accepted):

**Use the `tr` command**

```bash
echo "/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5" \
| tr " " "\n"
```

Found on http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/67831-replace-space-new-line.html

Comment: tr was my first thought as well, although there are so many ways to do it! This is pretty much EXACTLY what `tr` is for, though!

Comment: +1, but as a comment: That does not work if the filenames contain spaces themselves

Comment: @BonsiScott If the filenames contain spaces, the whole exercise becomes pointless.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the sequence \n represents a newline because... it's in the documentation. I mean : when writing `'\n'` (or `"\n"`) in the shell, tr and sed do not see an actual newline, they see "a backslash then the letter n".
In fact, giving an actual newline (can be obtained with `$'\n'` in bash) would work with `tr` (e.g. `tr " " $'\n'` works) but _not_ with `sed` (e.g. `sed $'s/ /\n/g'` does not work)

Comment: @YoungFrog `sed $'s/ /\\n/g'`. A literal newline has to be escaped with a backslash. But `sed 'y/ /\n/'` would be faster and also more portable.

Answer (score 32):

In this case I would use printf:

```bash
printf '%s\n' /path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5
```

If there are spaces *within* the one of the paths, you can quote that filepath in order to prevent it from being split on the spaces:

```bash
printf '%s\n' /path/to/file '/path/to/file with spaces' /path/to/another/file
```

To transform text in general, `tr` is your best bet, as covered in an existing answer.

Comment: A quick note from the future: thanks for posting this solution, it's been very reliable for me, compared to using "echo".

Answer (score 17):

Be pragmatic, use GNU `sed`!!

```bash
    sed -i 's/\s\+/\n/g' file
```

The above says to substitute one or more whitespace characters (`\s\+`) with a newline (`\n`).

The `-i` parameter stands for changing the file "in place".

This is more or less "substitute /one space or more/ for /newline/ globally".

Comment: If you have multiple spaces between text then you will get blank lines. You need to add a '+' after the \s to indicate that you want to match at least one spaces as apposed to exactly one space. ie. sed 's/\s+/\n/g'

Comment: Does it work for `'/path/to/file with spaces`

Comment: @Timo no, every space will be translated into a linebreak, you could use ` /` as the break point and then inject the `/` again but that'll be buggy with some edge cases like `/path/with space before slash /and then more`.

Comment: use `-i` to make changes to original file. so `sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' file -i`

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you have a string with spaces as separators:

```bash
    newline_separated=${space_separated// /$'\n'}
```

However, you're probably asking the wrong question. (Not necessarily, for example this might come up in a makefile.) A space-separated list of file names does not really work: what if one of the file names contained spaces?

If a program receives file names as arguments, don't join them with spaces. Use `"$@"` to access them one by one. Although `echo "$@"` prints the arguments with spaces in between, that's due to `echo`: it prints its arguments with spaces as separators. `somecommand "$@"` passes the file names as separate arguments to the command. If you want to print the arguments on separate lines, you can use

```bash
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

If you do have space-separated file names and you want to put them in an array to work on them, you can use an unquoted variable expansion to split the value at characters on `IFS` (you'll need to disable wildcard expansion with `set -f`, otherwise glob patterns will be expanded in the value):

```bash
    space_separated_list='/path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3'
    IFS=' '; set -f
    eval "array=(\$space_separated_list)"
    for x in "${array[@]}"; do …
```

You can encapsulate this in a function that restores the `-f` setting and the value of `IFS` when it is done:

```bash
    split_list () {
      local IFS=' ' flags='+f'
      if [[ $- = *f* ]]; then flags=; fi
      set -f
      eval "$1=(\$2)"
      set $flags
    }
    split_list array '/path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3'
    for x in "${array[@]}"; do …
```

Comment: Changing the correct answer to this one. I think it's more correct to research how I got to a space-separated list, and retrieve that information in another way.

It would be cool for learners like me if you comment a bit your snipnet, telling us what do things like the local var IFS or the condition $- = *f* do. That kind of things a person that uses bash few times don't knows.

Comment: @laconbass I've added a short explanation. Look up `set -f` and `IFS` in the bash manual if you want all the details. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping/16195#16195

Comment: @Guilles That short explanation is enough for me, and i think it will be for many others. Ty for your time

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to `tr` from @laconbass, you can also use `xargs` in this case:

```bash
echo "/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4  /path/to/file5"\
    | xargs -n1
```

The advantage is that it works even with multiple whitespaces, which `tr` doesn't.

Comment: It would work with multiple spaces _between_ paths, certainly, but like most of the other answered here it does not handle spaces _in_ the path names

Comment: @ChrisDavies Yes it does so long as you put the paths with spaces in inner quotes. Example: `echo "/path/to/file '/path/to/my file'" | xargs -n1`

Answer (score 4):

The question on the title: `replace space with new line`

The simple, quick, brute force solution is to do exactly that, replace all spaces with new lines:

```bsh
echo "$input" | tr ' ' '\n'
echo "$input" | sed 'y/ /\n/'
echo "$input" | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

## Filenames

But in your question you are listing a list of paths:

```bsh
echo '/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5' > test.txt
```

Using the solution above will not work for filenames with spaces (or newlines).

## Better

But we can use a two characters delimiter:  `/` (**space slash**)
That pair of characters could only exist at the beginning of a new (absolute) path:

```bsh
input='/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/one space /path/to/new
line /path/to/file5'

$ printf '%s\n' "$input" | sed 's# /#\n/#g'

/path/to/file
/path/to/file2
/path/to/one space
/path/to/new
line
/path/to/file5
```

For relative paths, we need to also allow paths that start with `./` or `../`:

```bsh
$ cat test2.txt 
/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/one space /path/to/new
line /path/to/file5 ./path/to/file ../path/to/file2 ./path/to/one space ./path/to/new
line ./path/to/file5 ../path/to/file ../path/to/file2 ../path/to/one space ../path/to/new
line ../path/to/file5


$ sed 's# \([.]\{0,2\}/\)#\n\1#g' test2.txt 
/path/to/file
/path/to/file2
/path/to/one space
/path/to/new
line
/path/to/file5
./path/to/file
../path/to/file2
./path/to/one space
./path/to/new
line
./path/to/file5
../path/to/file
../path/to/file2
../path/to/one space
../path/to/new
line
../path/to/file5
```

## Best

For path names with newlines it is better to quote each pathname.

```bsh
$ sed -e '1s/^/"/' -e 's# \([.]\{0,2\}/\)#"\n"\1#g' -e '$s/$/"/' test2.txt

"/path/to/file"
"/path/to/file2"
"/path/to/one space"
"/path/to/new
line"
"/path/to/file5"
"./path/to/file"
"../path/to/file2"
"./path/to/one space"
"./path/to/new
line"
"./path/to/file5"
"../path/to/file"
"../path/to/file2"
"../path/to/one space"
"../path/to/new
line"
"../path/to/file5"
```

Comment: "More best", change the way the list of file names was captured in the first place, so that either no splitting is required or that an otherwise unused character separates the items

Comment: Nice answer. Here's a slight variation of your best solution using perl to make the output NUL delimited (in case the filenames contain quote characters): `perl -pe 's/\s+([.]{0,2}\/)/\0\1/g' test2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

```
echo "/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5" | sed 's/ /\
'/g
```

Notice the use of Enter key after backslash in the `sed` command.

Comment: what prons and cons has `sed` over `tr`?

Comment: Your comfort level :-)  I think you can do more with `sed` as it is an editor rather than simply translate characters.

Comment: `sed` can do so much more, but is totally overkill for this. `tr` is the right tool for THIS job, but knowledge of `sed` and regexes will certainly come in handy later!

Answer (score 1):

option1:

```
echo "/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5"|perl -pne  "s/ /\n/g"
```

option2:

````
echo "/path/to/file /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5"|awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n",$0);print }'```
````

output

```
/path/to/file
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file3
/path/to/file4
/path/to/file5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, assuming the line is in a variable called `line`:

```
for path in $line;do echo $path;done
```

This makes use of the fact that Bash splits its arguments on whitespace by default and that `echo` appends a newline to its input by default.

Comment: I tried this on my ubuntu system before i posted this question and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo word1 word2 ... | sed -e 'y/ /\n/;P;D'
```

is another method to turn single-space-separated words into newline separated.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Sample Input:

```
/path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3
```

Split on whitespace (before forwardslash):

```
~$ raku -ne '.put for .split(/ \s <?before "/">/);'  file
```

Sample Output:

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file3
```

This is just to get you started. What's nice is that if you just add `.IO` to the code above, Raku's object system from this point will recognize **IO::Path** objects, including the correct path separator (backslash for Windows). The objective is to make your code more portable from platform to platform. Below results from adding `.IO` and change the `put` call to `say`:

```
~$ raku -ne '.IO.say for .split(/ \s <?before "/">/);'  file 
"/path/to/file".IO
"/path/to/file2".IO
"/path/to/file3".IO
```

Reading your file containing the list of files, and extracting the filenames, a.k.a. `basename`:

```
~$ raku -ne '.IO.say for .split(/ \s <?before "/">/);'  file 
file1
file2
file3
```

Finally, you can output the contents of the first file, by `slurp`ing in the `[0]`th element. Assuming these are relative paths, from the directory you're in on the command line you use `~` tilde to concatenate the path either with a leading `.` dot, or with `$*CWD`:

```
raku -ne '.map($*CWD ~ *).IO.slurp.put for .split(/ \s <?before "/">/)[0];'
#returns output of first file in list (assumes relative paths)
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path
https://raku.org

Answer (score -1):

The following script is easy to understand and easy to use.

```
cat filename | tr ' ' '\n' | tee filename
```

Comment: The essence of your answer (`tr`) is the same as in the accepted answer. Beside that your answer has following issues: a) the command is not indented with 4 spaces (-> markdown layout) b) Your use of `cat` is useless (you can replace it with `< filename tr ' ' '\n'`). c) Your output filename is the same as the input filename. With that you create a data race.

Comment: apart from maxschlepzig's correct analysis, this is not a script, but a bunch of connected commands that have a name hardcoded (as script would hopefully have a header specifying the shell to use and use two parameters to specify in and output). Apart from that 2 out of 3 people in my household do not find it easy to understand. Maybe that is is not representative, but keep in mind that something you yourself understand (or in this case think you understand) always seems easy.

Answer (score -1):

Here an example

```
list=$(cat index.txt | grep href=)
for iterator in $list
do
       echo $iterator
done
```

Here I have string with many links and space between every link, when you use *loops* it will solve your problem

Comment: Same answer as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105573/100397