# Bash - echo line by line, ignoring the space between the lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, echo

I had read the post on:
[bash - replace space with new line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105569/bash-replace-space-with-new-line),
but it does not helped to solve my issue.

```
   [My Directory]

[root@testlabs Config]# ls 
Archive Backup_Files
config_file.tgz
hostname1-config.uac
hostname2-config.uac
hostname3-config.uac
My-config_17Oct2014.tgz
non_extension-config_file1
non_extension-config_file2
[root@testlabs Config]#
```

I need to echo a list of MD5 Checksum results from a file. I am able to do so by doing this:

```
##IDENTIFY MD5 CHECKSUM##

 //To output the md5sum of the original file with a correct format to a temp file [md5<space><space>file_name]
ls $FULL_FILE_NAME | md5sum  $FULL_FILE_NAME > /tmp/md5sum.tmp

//To compare the md5sum of the orignal file with the md5sum of the backup copies in the archive directory
ls $CONFIG_ARCHIVE_DIR | grep -i --text $CONFIG_FILE_HOSTNAME-$FILE_TIMESTAMP.tgz | md5sum -c /tmp/md5sum.tmp >> /tmp/md5sum2.tmp

##COMPARING MD5 CHECKSUM##

 if [ -s /tmp/md5sum2.tmp ];
 then
   echo ""
   echo "Comparison of MD5 for files archived:"
   echo '---------------------------------------'
   /bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp
 fi
```

and this will be the result when it was executed:
(echo of the CONTENTS in /tmp/md5sum2.tmp)

```
Comparison of MD5 for files archived:
---------------------------------------
 config_file.tgz: OK
 hostname1-config.uac: OK
 hostname2-config.uac: OK
 hostname3-config.uac: OK
 My-config_17Oct2014.tgz: OK
 non_extension-config_file1: OK
 non_extension-config_file1: OK
```

***## WANTED ##***

However I would like the result to be display in this way:

```
Comparison of MD5 for files archived:
---------------------------------------
 - config_file.tgz: OK
 - hostname1-config.uac: OK
 - hostname2-config.uac: OK
 - hostname3-config.uac: OK
 - My-config_17Oct2014.tgz: OK
 - non_extension-config_file1: OK
 - non_extension-config_file2: OK
```

---

I tried doing this,
(echo the CONTENTS of /tmp/md5sum2.tmp into /tmp/md5sum3.tmp with the '-' infront)

### 1)

```
 ##COMPARING MD5 CHECKSUM##

  if [ -s /tmp/md5sum2.tmp ];
  then
  echo ""
  echo "Comparison of MD5 for files archived:"
  echo '---------------------------------------'
  /bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp

  for CONFIG_FILES in `/bin/cat /tmp/md5sum2.tmp`
  do
/bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp | grep $CONFIG_FILES > /tmp/md5sum3.tmp
  done

  for MD5_COMPARE in $(/bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum3.tmp)
  do
   echo -e " - $MD5_COMPARE\n"
  done
 fi
```

### Result 1)

```
Comparison of MD5 for files archived:
 ---------------------------------------
 - config_file.tgz:
 - OK
 - hostname1-config.uac:
 - OK
 - hostname2-config.uac:
 - OK
 - hostname3-config.uac:
 - OK
 - My-config_17Oct2014.tgz.tgz:
 - OK
 - non_extension-config_file1:
 - OK
 - non_extension-config_file2:
 - OK
```

### 2)

```
for MD5_COMPARE in $(/bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum3.tmp)

  do
  echo -n " - $MD5_COMPARE"
  done
```

### Result 2)

```
  Comparison of MD5 for files archived:
  ---------------------------------------
- config_file.tgz: - OK - hostname1-config.uac: - OK - hostname2-config.uac: - OK - 
  hostname3-config.uac: - OK - My-config_17Oct2014.tgz: - OK - non_extension-config_file1: -
OK - non_extension-config_file2: - OK
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. When asking this type of question, it is essential that you also show us your input. Please [edit] your question and include the contents of `/tmp/md5sum3.tmp`.

Comment: Hi Terdon, thanks! :) I had edited the question.

Comment: I think we may have just gotten our edits crossed. I was editing at the same time you were, please make sure I did not remove anything important. I was just removing the extra whitespace.

Comment: Also, please [edit] and show us your input file. We don't know what `$FULL_FILE_NAME` or `$CONFIG_ARCHIVE_DIR` are. We also don't need to. We do need to know what the files you are comparing look like.

Comment: Yes, I am adding some comments. I think Costas's solution worked out for me already :)

Comment: Cool. In that case, please remember to [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read file line by line standard procedure is

```
while IFS= read -r MD5_COMPARE
do
  echo "- $MD5_COMPARE"
done < /tmp/md5sum2.tmp | /bin/sort -d
```

But `sed` should work too

```
/bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp | sed 's/^/ -/'
```

Comment: This is definitely a perfect job for sed.

Comment: @Costas Thank you Costas /bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp | sed 's/^/ -/' worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the output from `sort` to `sed` and replace one space with `-`:

```
if [ -s /tmp/md5sum2.tmp ];
then
        echo ""
        echo "Comparison of MD5 for files archived:"
        echo '---------------------------------------'
        /bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp | sed 's/\(^ *\) \( [^ ]\)/\1-\2/'
fi
```

Result:

```
Comparison of MD5 for files archived:
---------------------------------------
    - My-config_17Oct2014.tgz: OK
    - config_file.tgz: OK
    - hostname1-config.uac: OK
    - hostname2-config.uac: OK
    - hostname3-config.uac: OK
    - non_extension-config_file1: OK
    - non_extension-config_file1: OK
```

Comment: @Win.T my answer assumes that your initial file has spaces at the beginning of the line, however now I'm not sure if this is correct or your question is just wrongly formatted.

Comment: The solution for /bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp | sed 's/\(^ *\) \( [^ ]\)/\1-\2/' does not worked. It returns the same result as using /bin/sort -d /tmp/md5sum2.tmp. The file /tmp/md5sum2.tmp contains the following: config_file.tgz: OK My-config_17Oct2014.tgz: OK hostname1-config.uac: OK hostname2-config.uac: OK hostname3-config.uac: OK non_extension-config_file2: OK non_extension-config_file1: OK @jimij

Comment: @Win.T edit you question, add content of original file properly formatted.

Comment: @jimij , thank you I had edited my question :)