# How can I replace all spaces outside double quotes by \n?

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting

I have a `$variable` that has many double quoted paths separated by spaces

```
echo $variable

"/home/myuser/example of name with spaces" "/home/myuser/another example with spaces/myfile"
```

The number of paths on my variable can vary and it's not something under control. It can e.g. be like the following examples:

```
example 1: "path1" "path2" "path3" "path4"
example 2: "path1" "path2" "path3" "path4" "path5" "path6" path7" "path8"
example 3: "path1" "path2" "path3" 
example 4: "path1" "path2" "path3" "path4" "path5" "path6"
```

I want to replace all spaces outside the double quotes into a new line (`\n`) while preserving the spaces that are inside quotes. Using `echo $variable | tr " " "\n"` like in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105570/103357) answer doesn't work for me because it replaces all the spaces by new lines. How can I do it?

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "${variable[@]}"`

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks for replying. But for some reason this command is just replacing the last character from the line, it's not replacing the spaces in the middle...

Comment: How is "$variable" created?

Comment: @jasonwryan The steeldriver answer solved the problem. I was actually testing on the terminal declaring it with `variable="\"path1\" \"path2\" \"path3\""`... But now I see that it needs to be declared as an array to make it work with the printf.

Comment: I would handle this as CSV data and use a CSV parser with space as the field separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elements are *always* double quoted, then you can replace quote-space-quote with quote-newline-quote:

```
$ sed 's/" "/"\n"/g' <<< "$variable"
"/home/myuser/example of name with spaces"
"/home/myuser/another example with spaces/myfile"
```

or (using shell parameter substitution)

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${variable//\" \"/\"$'\n'\"}"
"/home/myuser/example of name with spaces"
"/home/myuser/another example with spaces/myfile"
```

But it would be simpler if you can modify your script to use an array:

```
$ vararray=("/home/myuser/example of name with spaces" "/home/myuser/another example with spaces/myfile")
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${vararray[@]}"
"/home/myuser/example of name with spaces"
"/home/myuser/another example with spaces/myfile"
```